# VBA MS-WORD Trouble with sendkeys

Tags: vba, ms-word, sendkeys

I'm having some issue with this code

```
Private Sub CortarSobrantes()
'Procedimiento que llama al comando "Comprimir imágenes" con parámetros
    With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=6382)
        SendKeys "%T%n%C{ENTER}", False ' Las letras equivalen a los accesos de teclado en la ventana, ~ para ejecucion
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

If I hit Run (F5) inside the project, it runs OK, but when I try to call it from a button shortcut it doesn't catch the `SendKeys`. This also happens if I try to run it step by step (F8)

BTW `%T%n%C` is for Spanish command combination (all images, not compress, without resolution change and deleting cropped areas)

The reason I'm using `SendKeys` is that I'm trying to remove cropped areas within a function in order to call it from a button, so I could skip marking the options. As far as I know, there's nothing in the object model that allows this.

Am I missing something with the focus?

Comment: I agree with macro man's assessment of avoiding the use of SendKeys. It seems you're using this because there's nothing in the object model that lets you access the commands in the "Compress Pictures" dialog? (As a matter of fact, how do you get the dialog box to show from within the UI? I could only get to it via the CommandBars command you show in your code...) Based on experience: have you tried changing the SendKeys "Wait" parameter from False to True?

Comment: I've tried but with no difference. Is there anyway to pass parameters to the control with thecommandbarcontrol.parameter property??

Comment: Not that I've ever found. CommandBarControl.Parameter is very, very old and doesn't apply to the newer technologies introduced in Word 2007 and later (Ribbon, task panes, etc.)

Comment: About the only workable idea I can come up with would be to create two fairly simple documents: one without the settings and one with the settings you make in the dialog box. Print out both documents' WordOpenXML (Document.Content.WordOpenXML) to new documents and compare the XML, looking for these settings. If the Word UI doesn't make a fuss, you should be able to change the original WordOpenXML to the altered WordOpenXML by changing this XML string, then writing it back to the document using Document.Content.InsertXML. This doens't work with everything, but it's worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but in general the `SendKeys()` method is usually avoided in VBA because it's unreliable and buggy at best.

`SendKeys()` will send virtual keystrokes to whichever window has focus at the time of execution - so timing is everything.

If you know the **exact** text in the caption of your window you can use the `AppActivate()` method to force focus just before using `SendKeys()`

Moreover, `SendKeys()` is more widely regarded as a "final attempt" or workaround because 90% of the time you can use [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) to get the same result reliably although more advanced knowledge of VBA/programming is required when using Win API

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having trouble with the SendKeys-statement.
I'm trying to send Alt= to a Word document. Thereby changing some mahematical formula in an equation field. For instance: ((x_1 q+x_2 p)/(p+q),(y_1 q+y_2 p)/(p+q))
After some time I found that the SendKeys-statement works as advertised only and ONLY if there's no further statement in my macro.
I know this is a bit awkward, but there it is.
Consider the following:

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim test As String
    test = ActiveWindow.Selection.Text

    SendKeys "%=", True

'    MsgBox test

End Sub
```

This works fine.
Copy/paste the formula above in a Word-document, open VBA in Word, make a new Module and copy/paste the Sub above into it.
Select the formula.
You must start the Sub form the Macro's menu (Alt+F8).
You'll notice that the formula will change in an equation-field and gets centered in the middle.
Run the macro again and the formula is changed back in standard text-format.
Now activate the MsgBox-statement and you'll notice that the SendKeys-statement doesn't work anymore.
I know this is hardly a workaround for the problem, but maybe someone will find this information useful!